# Mouseenter and Mousleave firing in reverse order on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firefox, d3.js

I have the following code firing these events in reverse order only on Firefox, it works perfectly on every other browser, I am sort of at a loss as to why they fire in reverse order.

the events:

```
function highlightNodeLinks(highlightNode, i) {
    var remainingNodes = [],
        nextNodes = [],
        strokeOpacity = 0,
        traverse;

    if ( d3.select(this).attr('data-hover') === '1' ) {
      d3.select(this).attr('data-hover', '0');
      strokeOpacity = 0.2;
    } else {
      d3.select(this).attr('data-hover', '1');
      strokeOpacity = 0.5;
    }

    traverse = [{
      linkType : 'sourceLinks',
      nodeType : 'target'
    }, {
      linkType : 'targetLinks',
      nodeType : 'source'
    }];

    traverse.forEach(function (step) {
      highlightNode[step.linkType].forEach(function (linkPath) {
        remainingNodes.push(linkPath[step.nodeType]);
        highlightLink(linkPath.id, strokeOpacity);
      });

      while (remainingNodes.length) {
        nextNodes = [];
        remainingNodes.forEach(function (newNode) {
          newNode[step.linkType].forEach(function (linkPath) {
            nextNodes.push(linkPath[step.nodeType]);
            highlightLink(linkPath.id, strokeOpacity);
          });
        });
        remainingNodes = nextNodes;
      }
    });
  }

  function highlightLink(id, opacity) {
    d3.select('#link-' + id).style('stroke-opacity', opacity);
  }
```

the order of the function calls:

```
 node = svg.append('g').selectAll('.node')
  .data(customerData.nodes)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr('class', 'node')
  .attr('data-hover', '1')
  .attr('transform', function (d) {
      return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
  })
  .on('mouseenter', highlightNodeLinks)
  .on('mouseleave', highlightNodeLinks)
```

again, these seem to fire in reverse order only in FF and I am not sure exactly why.

Comment: Where are `id` and `opacity` defined?

Comment: @charlietfl updated with the full functions

Comment: I've found a couple bugs on Firefox (too much for my taste). Bugs with maths, dates, graph, string. Try to do a research on Firefox's bug page :)